# What is the performance overhead of using Proxy in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Has anyone created a performance report highlighting the overhead of extending the [Proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) class in ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson Dunstan answered this question on my behalf back in September; credit should go to him!  http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1392

Answer (score 0):

I did a little Googling and didn't find much.  I would assume that the performance wouldn't be great since they are dynamic objects and you go down the whole compiler can't optimize because it can't guarantee anything type of deal.